# 'const decltype((a))' does not declare a const reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

Today I saw some code like this:

```
int a = 0;
const decltype((a)) x = 10; // Error

const int b = 0;
decltype ((b)) y = 42; // Correct
```

I can see why the correct code is correct, but I can't see why the incorrect code is incorrect.

I tested it, and just found it a little wierd.

`const decltype((a)) x = 10;` This should be defining a `const int&` right?  But it doesn't compile! `error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'int'`.

I changed it to `const decltype((a)) x = a;` then it compiles.

Well, is `x` a const reference? No, I found that it's a non-const reference. I can modify `a`'s value through `x`.

Why didn't the `const` modifier take effect?

Comment: The `const` is applied to the reference (and ignored), rather than the type referred to.

Comment: combining `decltype` with modifiers works exactly like applying modifiers to a `typedef`-ed type.  It is NOT text substitution.

Comment: @T.C. @ben-voigt Oh, I got it. So `const` is applied to the whole body of `int&` to be `const reference to int`, not just combined to it to be `const int&`, reference to const int... Right?

Comment: `int` is a more "inner" type in the `int&` type and const is sticking to the outer one which is a reference. Just add const to the right and read the resulting type: "const reference to int"

Comment: @ixSci Thank you, I completely understand your meaning. But I'm curious why are you guys all commenting instead of answering?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Incorrect part is incorrect because `const` is applied to the full type which is `int&` and adding `const` to `int&` makes it `int& const` which is **const reference to int**. But the reference is `const` by its very nature so the const part is just ignored. Hence the resulting type is still `int&`